# AngularJS: Custom dropdown directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angularjs-material

So currently I'm using [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select) dropdown directive, here is an example of usage

```
<md-select ng-model="scopeClinic">
    <md-option ng-value="clinic.id" ng-repeat="clinic in clinics">{{ clinic.name }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

As you see, usage is pretty simple, but I'm not really satisfied how the library behaves in most cases and now I want to create my own dropdown directive, using bootstrap template

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to make a transfer with minimal changes, just changing `md-select` to `my-select` and `md-option` to `my-option` as well. I read a lot of documentation, but still I have no idea where to start from. Currently the most question for me is to understand how to put `my-option` directive into `my-select` directive, make a link between them, convert `<my-option>` into `<li>` options (I'm not sure even if I'm thinking in a right way). If someone can show me a base example where I can start that would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: well, `md-select` is directive also that uses `<select>`. if you want to write your own directive, start from `<select>` and grab sources from angular material.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I want to completely remove angular material from my project

Comment: @LuninRoman do you want only the styling or the javascript functionalities too.

Comment: @Naren Murali There is no functionalities that I want to transfer.

Comment: @LuninRoman have you checked [bootstrap material dropdown](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/#dropdown-menu)

Comment: No, because I do not want to have one more dependency in the project, I just want to replace all material dropdown with bootstrap